# Where to find the codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm new to ASP, just inherited a database application. I'm having trouble with probably the most basic thing... how the file structures are set up.

I've confirmed I've found the right .aspx file of the page I'm working on, but it's just the template. I am looking for the code that is behind that file.

The page starts with:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/print.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Servicecallreport.aspx.cs" Inherits="CrisisSupportApp.Secure.Reports.BriefSummaryReport" %>
```

I've done a search for "Servicecallreport.aspx.cs" and "CrisisSupportApp.Secure.Reports.BriefSummaryReport" on the server and I get nothing.

Where should I be looking for these .asp.cs files?

Answer (score 2):

Look for a version control system like git, subversion, or TFS. The code is likely in there. ASP.Net does not need to deploy those code files to the web server at all, but instead allows you to pre-compile them.

Comment: This is all running off of an ancient windows server.  Also... wouldn't there have to be somewhere in the .aspx file that said "We're using a version control system.  Go here to find the files:"

Comment: No, you can't tell if a file is in source control just by looking at the ASPX.

Comment: So where would I look?

Comment: The web server doesn't care where the files are. **It has a dll file**, which from the web server's point of view is better. You'll have to ask your boss or team mates about where to look and how to get access to version control. If that doesn't exist, and you've taken over someone else's workstation, see if you can get access to their old user profile and look in there.

Answer (score 1):

try:
(what ever your root is)\CrisisSupportApp\Secure\Reports\BriefSummaryReport.cs